# WORDPRESS Trouble with simple non profit theme

Tags: wordpress, template-engine

I've created a web application based on this free Wordpress Theme:

http://vandelaydesign.com/blog/wp-themes/simple-non-profit/

All ok in localhost environment, but when I uploaded the site on remote (PHP + MySQL + Email active), the admin panel changes, and shows me only a part of whole admin menu.

e.g., admin panel doesn't show me the theme customization page and the slideshow customization page, that instead, in local environment, I have it.

Can you help me??? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

It might be that the live server is running a different version of PHP, or has config settings that make it different from your local environment.

However, my guess is that you haven't modified the database properly when you transferred it and that is the cause of your problem (I would suggest that it's nothing to do with the theme).

Moving Wordpress databases from your local development environment to live can be a massive pain because Wordpress (and lots of plugin/theme developers) use serialized arrays to store data. So if you do a find-and-replace on the database to replace your old url with the new one, you will disable lots of things like config settings and widgets (text widgets specifically, but there's loads of stuff you end up having to recreate).

Download this file;

http://interconnectit.com/124/search-and-replace-for-wordpress-databases/

and upload it to the server and access it directly in your browser. Run through the quick form and perform a serialized array-friendly find and replace on your database urls. Job done.

Delete the database on the live server and copy the local version of the database again, but this time use the instructions in the thread above to change all the instances of your local url path to the live domain url.

Comment: Hi McNab, thanks for your reply. I checked my wp-config.php and it's ok, I put in the right way the parameter gave me by hosting service. The PHP version is not properly the same (local: 5.3.8, remote: 5.2.17): do you think this can be a problem?

Comment: My bad - sorry I meant the second part of that answer.  I've edited my answer and just pasted in the section that's relevant.  Typically when you've transferred a Wordpress site and lost a load of settings, widgets, customization pages etc, it's because that info has been stored in serialized arrays.  The technique described above will solve these issues.

Comment: Ok, I try and post results

Comment: I've just tried search & replace script, that you suggested me. I used the script to replace, in my db, "localhost" with the url of my host (www.nameofmyspace.it). The script gave this: "In the process of replacing "localhost" with "www.nameofmyspace.it" we scanned 13 tables with a total of 820 rows, 312 cells were changed and 248 db update performed and it all took 0.160075 seconds".

Comment: But the problem has not been fixed!

Comment: When I uploaded my site to live, unexpectly the whole code of a php page (functions.php) was arranged on only one row: the first. But since on the first row of the code there's a comment (with //), as the result all the code was considered as a comment!!! Because of this "bug", the admin panel appeared incomplete. I really hope this fix can be useful to someone, it cost me a few days ;)

Comment: Glad you found the problem - thanks for updating the thread on the solution, you can always post it as an answer and mark it correct.